# How to make a property or field accessible to other classes

Tags: c#

I want to put the contents of a large file (1GB) into a List and be able to use the List in other classes.

I am currently trying to do it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        var myFile = File.ReadLines("File.txt");
        var myList = new List<string>(myFile);
    }
}
```

But I want to use the List in other classes, like: `MyClass.MyMethod.myList` which is not possible.

I think the solution is to put the fields directly into the class (without methods), but that's not possible either because I can't use `var` in the class directly:

```
    var myFile = File.ReadLines("File.txt");
    var myList = new List<string>(myFile);
```

Comment: `public static List<string> myList = File.ReadLines("File.txt").ToList();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Answer it ;)

Comment: @SelmanGenç - This site is to ask programming questions, I didn't know this so it is a question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick

```
class MyClass
{
   public static List<string> myList{ get; set;}

   public static void MyMethod()
   {
      var myFile = File.ReadLines("File.txt");
      myList = new List<string>(myFile);
   }
}
```

Or if your're after a one liner and don't need any further processing, what @DmitryBychenko said in his comments